# Kivy StackLayout not stacking floatLayouts

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to stack several instances of a floatlayout, each with one button inside. I am using flaotlayout as I want to later adjust the relative position of the button horizontaly across the float layout while keeping the vertical position. When I use pos_hint to position the button in the float layout it works fine but I want to use pos = (x,y) and this results in all buttons overlappying so i can only see one... I would appreciate if anyone could tell me where I am going wrong!

i think the button is taking the pos of the window rather then the parent widget, is this the case??

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button



class BreaksPanel(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.size_hint = None, None
        self.width = 5000 
        self.height = 36 

        btn = Button(text='My Button', size_hint=(None, None), size=(75, 36), pos = (0,0) )  # pos_hint={"x":0, "y":0}) works fine but not pos = (0,0)
        self.add_widget(btn)



class BreaksWindow(StackLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.orientation = "tb-lr" 
        for i in range(10):
            B = BreaksPanel()
            self.add_widget(B)



class Example(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BreaksWindow()
        return layout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your use of `FloatLayout`. In a `FloatLayout`, you can position its children anywhere and that is not restricted  to the inside of the `FloatLayout`. So your `Buttons` are all positioned at the same `pos` `(0,0)`. I think you are expecting the `FloatLayout` to act like a `RelativeLayout`, where `pos` of `(0,0)` is the lower right of the `Layout`. So a simple fix is to just make the `BreaksPanel` extend `RelativeLayout`:

```
class BreaksPanel(RelativeLayout):
```